# Tabbing comments in emacs py-mode?

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I'm using python-mode.el, and when I try to indent comments, it always wants to put them all the way to the left. I want them indented in line with the rest of the code. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Recent python-mode.el comes with a customizable variable
py-indent-comments
When t, comment lines are indented.

get it from 
http://launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 0):

Also running python-mode.el and when I tab a comment it cycles through the indentation levels.  What version of emacs are you using?

**edit** getting the behavior you describe if there is a non-space immediately following the #.  I always put a space after, but it sounds like a bug to me.  I'd ask on the python-mode.el list.

Comment: For me it cycles, until it gets to the left margin, then it just sits there... emacs 23.1.1